How to avoid table locks in Snowflake when using Entity Framework Core 8?
I'm encountering a locking issue when using Entity Framework Core 8 with Snowflake. The error message I'm seeing is:
Inner Exception: Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException (0x80004005): Error: Statement '01b55fa2-3201-4a18-0004-75ee01577e7a' has locked table 'XYZ' in transaction 1719822856599000000 and this lock has not yet been released.

From
    public async Task Create(T entity)
    {
        DbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        await Save(cancellationToken: default);
    }

This occurs while saving data. We're using EF Core for data access and Snowflake as the backend. We are writing into snowflake too frequently.
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

what is the Save methods? can you share the code inside.

@sa-es-ir public async Task Save(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

Is this calling by API or how many calls per second? I'm skeptical about CancellationToken.

10/20 calls per seconds to write into one table

Can you use the actual cancellationToken?, like if you're using API then it's in HttpContext.RequestAborted

ok, but how's that going to help. pls help me understand

Are there also calls to read from that table? If there are check that these read calls are also calling SaveChanges(). EF's DbContext works with transactions internally which applies to both Read and Write and during a read if you don't call SaveChanges it will initate a rollback as the DbContext is disposed. In high volume systems this can contribute to locking issues. Also ensure that the lifetime scope of your DbContext dependency is "Scoped" or Per-Request. On the database side are you partitioning the table in question?

The question doesn't show tunning code that causes the exception.
